# how to using jade Mixin in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, mixins

In jade, i'm make test mixins

```
mixin test(testName)
  #test
   span Test String
```

But i want using this in javascript (this is declare in jade file)

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    $( document ).on( "click", "#addBtn", function() {
        $("#list").append( I WANT USE MIXIN THIS PLACE );
    });
```

How to use mixin in javascript?

Comment: Or really any jade code

Comment: Mixins work when jade is rendered on server. You can't use this on browser. You have to write the javascript equivalent to modify DOM yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a Jade mixin in a JavaScript file because Jade templates are rendered on server side.

Comment: This is not necessarily true you can pre-fab your templates via browserify / webpack and access them on the client side as well.
`
directive: ($log) ->
    template: require('../../../html/includes/map/_navigation.jade')()
`